# Iteed SD card breakout info for Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, library, sd-card

I got an SD card breakout from an online shop, its the iteed kind without the level shifter, it has the 3.3 / 5 V switch. I cannot find any libraries or write example for it.

Has anyone dealt with it before with Arduino? I have tried finding info but I only get the level shifter kind that has the MOSI pins!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdK9S.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use standard Arduino SD library or the SdFat library. All SD card 'modules' are only a holder and eventually level converters. The SPI device is the SD card itself.

Set the SD adapter to the voltage of your board, connect it to power and SPI bus, choose some pin as SS pin, insert SD card and it must work.

Pins: MISO is master in slave out, MOSI is master out slave in. DO is data out, DI is data in. SD card is slave, so MISO to DO and MOSI to DI

Comment: Thanks, do you by any chance know how to connect it as all the examples show mosi and miso pins but i dont have those on this breakout, even in the data log example it asks for mosi and miso pins but i only have DO, CLK, DI, CS, i can only find CLK and CS in examples

Comment: MISO is master in slave out, MOSI is master out slave in. DO is data out, DI is data in. SD card is slave, so MISO to DO and MOSI to DI

Answer (score 1):

So, a quick google for "Itead SD card breakout" comes up with [their website/wiki](https://www.itead.cc/sd-micro-sd-card-breakout-module.html) where there is a schematic.  Can't believe you did not try this.  It is just that - a breakout board.  It will allow you to connect Arduino to an SD card.  You can look up any generic example for SD + Arduino on the web.

They explicitly say

> It can work with 5V or 3.3V power supply, and both 5V/3.3V IO operation level. It can be controlled directly by a wide range of microcontrollers such as Arduino, AVR, PIC, ARM and MSP430.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, For anyone else struggling with this in the future.
Using arduino mega and iteed sd breakout withoit level shifter
G-Ground
DO-50
CLK-52
DI-51
CS-53
+-5V
then in the code before setup specify chip select to 53
Thanks for all the help.